# What's the point of autoboxing primitives in Java?

Tags: java, reference, pass-by-reference, boxing, unboxing

What's the point of having `Integer`, `Boolean` etc and call them "...boxing" if they don't behave like boxed objects that you can pass "by ref" and do unboxing to change their value?

Here's an example of "unboxing" that I actually found out isn't really unboxing.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean x = true;
        foo(x);
        System.out.println(x);

        Integer num = 9;
        bar(num);
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    private static void bar(Integer num) {
        num = 5;
    }

    static void foo(Boolean x){
            boolean y = false;
            x = y;
    }
```

it prints true and 9 btw.

Comment: Java is *pass by value*, always, with no exceptions. You're changing the reference inside the method, which won't affect the original passed value. Also recall that `Integer` is *immutable*.

Comment: But isn't `num = 5;` considered unboxing? So it changes the value inside the object and the ref to this object is the same. @MarounMaroun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
>   between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
>   classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a
>   Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is
>   called unboxing.
>   Reference :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

**What's the point of autoboxing primitives in Java?**

1. Could save you some time.

   `int s=4;
   Integer s1=new Integer(s); //without autoboxing
   Integr s1=s; //autoboxing (saves time and some code)
   int k=s1; //unboxing`

**Why Integer/Float/Decimal Objects?** (using Integers to explain)

2. An ArrayList of `Integers/Floats/Doubles etc.` as stated in Maroun's answer.
3. Some inbuilt functions in Java Library returns Integer objects. So you could simply store the values in a `primitive int` using autoboxing instead of using `returnedIntegerObject.intValue()` .

**Let us convert `String s="5"` to integer.**

- Using the inbuilt function `public static Integer valueOf(String s)`. As you can see the return type of this function is `Integer` and not `int`.

***Without Autoboxing:***

```
Integer a=Integer.valueOf(s);
int b= a.intValue(); //getting the primitive int from Integer Object
```

***With Autoboxing***

```
int b=Integer.valueOf(s); //saves code and time
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of having these wrapper classes is mostly for generics. In Java, if I wanted to make an ArrayList of integers, I CANNOT do the following:

```
ArrayList<int> intList = new ArrayList<int>()
```

This will not work, since generics only work for objects, and an "int" is a primitive. By using the wrapper,

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

I can fix this problem.